# InsertRowsAtIndexPaths error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `uitableview` and i try to append it by `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` function.
The `uitableview` appends nicely if i simply add data to the data source arrays, but gives me hard time inserting it by the mentioned above function.

Here is my code

```
    func insertData(){

// appending arrays
    answersdict.append(answersmain[answertitle1]![0]) // count 1
    resultanswers2d.append(carsmain[answertitle1]!) // count 3
    self.tableView.reloadData()

// inserting rows

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    let insertedIndexPathRange = 0..<carsmain[answertitle1]!.count + 1 // total count 4
    var insertedIndexPaths = insertedIndexPathRange.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 1) }

    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

My datasource count for sections is 2 (so section 1 exists) and for `numberOfRows` - its equal to `resultanswers2d[section].count + 1` which gives me 4

So i'm trying to insert 4 rows into the already appended array that has 4 possible rows in that section, but i'm constantly getting errors like

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (4), plus or minus inserted cells (4 inserted, 0 deleted)

or if i try to hard

> malloc_error

Got stuck. Need any insights. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the line to reload the table.

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths` updates the table accordingly.

The number of insertions and the positions in data source and table must match.

Comment: tried it - the following issue arises `The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)` so i have to insert sections as well?

Comment: yes, you have to add/insert all index paths including the appropriate sections

Comment: vadian, the issue has arisen - when i scroll the `withRowAnimation` insertion effect disappears and cells are simply inserted. do you know if there is any way to prevent it from happening and show the full animation despite the scroll? sorry for disturbance. thank you.

Comment: what if I do not implement any data source methods. I draw my table in storyBoard with static cells? how can i match insertions and the positions ?

Comment: actually the definition of static cells is that the cells aren't supposed to be changed

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't call `self.tableView.reloadData()`. The beginUpdate and endUpdate sections should suffice.

UPDATE:
Also, remember to [insert the new section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertSections:withRowAnimation:) too in the `beginUpdate` `endUpdate` block.

Comment: its a good idea. but removing this line gives me the following trouble `The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)` so i have to insert sections as well?

Comment: Yeah should be enough to call `insertSections` within the beginUpdate and endUpdate

Comment: Nicola, along with the insertion - there is another issue - if i scroll the effect of the withRowAnimation dissapears, cells are being reused and inserted the regular way without any effects. Do you have any insights how to prevent it from happening? Thank you !